# How to add value to a nested listed based on another list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I am not sure if the title makes sense but I have two lists:

```
a = [[8, 23, 45, 12, 78, 58], [2,3,4,1,5,4], [6, 7, 6, 9, 5, 8] , [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]]
b = [1, 0 , 1 , 2]
```

I want to try to multiply all of a[0] with b[0] and repeat this for all the others.
Thus, have an output like:

```
[8,23, 45, 12, 78, 58], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 6, 9, 8], [2, 4, 8, 14, 16]
```

I tried using for loop with nested loop but I end up multiply all of b with all of a. For example, I get:

```
8
23
45
12
78
58
0
0
0
0
0
6
```

and so on.

Is it possible to do with for loops? or Is there another way I should consider doing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop comprehension:

```
[[b[i]*v for v in suba] for i,suba in enumerate(a)]
```

output:

```
[[8, 23, 45, 12, 78, 58], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 6, 9, 5, 8], [2, 4, 8, 14, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

With loops and enumerate (to get the index of list items)

```
a = [[8, 23, 45, 12, 78, 58], [2,3,4,1,5,4], [6, 7, 6, 9, 5, 8] , [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]]
b = [1, 0 , 1 , 2]

c = [] # output list
for idx, val in enumerate(b):
    d=[]
    for i in a[idx]:
        d.append(i*val)
    c.append(d)
print(c)
```

output

```
[[8, 23, 45, 12, 78, 58], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 6, 9, 5, 8], [2, 4, 8, 14, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how to do this with a for loop you can do:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(b)):
  result.append([b[i] * num for num in a[i]])
```

if you print result you get:

```
[[8, 23, 45, 12, 78, 58], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [6, 7, 6, 9, 5, 8], [2, 4, 8, 14, 16]]
```